# How to make tools.run_flow function to work same as tools.run(deprecated method) in GmailApi authentication?

Tags: python-2.7, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I want to refresh tokens without providing authentication flow.can you guys help

Comment: what do you have so far? Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server#exchange_the_authorization_code_for_an_access_token), when users visit your app after a successful first-time authorization flow, your application can use a stored refresh token to authorize requests without prompting the user again.

> If you have already authenticated the user, your application can retrieve the refresh token from its database and store the token in a server-side session. If the refresh token is revoked or is otherwise invalid, you'll need to catch this and take appropriate action.

Here is an example that shows how to instantiate a service object and then authorize it to make API requests.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
# ...

def build_service(credentials):
  """Build a Gmail service object.

  Args:
    credentials: OAuth 2.0 credentials.

  Returns:
    Gmail service object.
  """
  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)
  return build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
```

Once OAuth 2.0 credentials have been retrieved, they can be used to authorize a Gmail service object and send requests to the API. Here is also an [example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample) in Google documentation.

Comment: Thanks @abielta I was using tools.run_flow even after authenticating once.I totally removed it and my code started running fine.